# Fix write-protected(read-only) filesystem

Tags: gparted, disk, read-only, fdisk

I made bootable usb drive , then USB drive was write protected. I used followng command

```
hrirks@hrirks-MS-7592:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors

 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cd3ed

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *      206848   125849426    62821289+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3       125851648   777533439   325840896    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       777533440   976771071    99618816    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       945315840   976771071    15727616   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       777535488   945313791    83889152    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 8179 MB, 8179941376 bytes
252 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1022 cylinders, total 15976448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x12108eb8

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

[image: i Tried the following command]
[image: Disk Shows]

[image]

Now Gparted Does not shows the device , but i can see drive in unity disk manager
What should i do now, to fix those errors?

Comment: Can you select /dev/sdb in Gparted with the drop-down selector in the upper right corner?

Comment: no i can't ,and i can't select via Gparted>Devices too

Comment: Looks like the drive is toast; time to toss it and get a new one.

Comment: I think that your usb drive is read only, please check it in other computer.

Comment: @psusi i already have 4 pendrives , but i need to fix this , so why not try ??

Comment: There isn't anything *to* try; the drive has stopped functioning.

Comment: @psusi ain't there any other ways left??